# Update Fragments within SlidingTabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager

According to [this Tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html) I've implemented Sliding Tabs.
The `ViewPager` holds 3 `Fragments`. In the first `Fragment` I add items to a sqlite table. In the second `Fragment` items of these tables are listed in a `ListFragment`.

How can I achieve to trigger an update of the second view to see these newly added items? I've already called a refresh function of the second `Fragment` which works fine within the second `Fragment` itself, but not in case I add items.

```
/* ListFragment */
@Override
public void refreshView() {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

/* ListAdapter */
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();

    mItems.clear();
    mItems = mItemDAO.getAllEntries();
}
```

`getAllEntries()` works fine. The Adapter should also work fine because that was the case when I used to work with the oldish `ActionBar` Tabs. After adding an item I swiped to the 2nd `Fragment` and I could see the new added items.

Comment: have u tried broadcast receiver for update second fragment view from db..whenever you add data from fragment one you should send broadcast message to second fragment for update UI

Comment: Not really. What would be different to my approach when I use the `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: I'm not sure about what "I've already called a refresh function of the second Fragment which works fine within the second Fragment itself", means, but if you are using a `ListFragment` you probably should refresh your `ListAdapter` calling `notifydatasetchanged()` in `onResume()`.

Comment: Before you insert data in sqlite you should register broadcast in fragment one and write code of broadcast receiver in second fragment.after inserting data in broadcastreceiver should be called from fragment  one to fragment second .In the fragment second you can clear data and restore again previous data in arraylist

Comment: please share refreshView method

Comment: @moictab I'm already doing this in my refresh function. I call `nofityDatasetChanged()` on the `ListAdapter`.

Comment: your not doing enough here. The refreshView method should make another query to the DB as i suggest below. simply calling notifyDatasetChanged will do nothing because your adapter is not getting any new data without the query.

Comment: call super.notifyDataSetChanged() after getting all entries

Comment: @inner_class7 That worked :-) But why? (Please move your answer that I can mark it as answered - if you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

call `super.notifyDataSetChanged()` after getting all entries.

```
 @Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    mItems.clear();
    mItems = mItemDAO.getAllEntries();

    // Update the ListAdapter now that you have the new Items
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This works because your telling the adapter to update before getting the new entries, it must be done after you get the items.

Also, For Fragments:

Regardless of your implementation details the flow to update Fragments based on data from other Fragments is as follows:

FragmentA -> Notify Parent Activity via interface -> Update FragmentB

First a User adds an item in Fragment A, upon successful completion of this item addition to the SQLite database use an interface to notify the Parent Activity to update its Fragment B.

Something like in `FragmentA` create:

```
 public interface IDataBaseChanged{
    void databaseUpdated(boolean updated);
 }
```

Parent Activity must `implements IDataBaseChanged`

in `FragmentA` create a local variable which can callback to the parent

```
 private IDataBaseChanged mCallback;


 public void addItemToDB(Object itemToAdd){
    // ... perform the operation which adds the Item then if this item
    // is actually added successfully meaning you get the long representation
    // of the newly added row id and its not -1, perform a callback

    // Callback method to tell the Parent Activity data was added
    mCallback.databaseUpdated(true);
 }
```

Make sure you Override onAttach in FragmentA and attach the interface to the Activity:

```
   @Override
   public void onAttach (Activity activity){
     try{
           mCallback = (IDataBaseChanged) activity;
        }catch(ClassCastException ex){
             Log.e("Interface", "Failed to implement interface in parent", ex); 
        }
   }
```

and in the Parent Activity:

```
  // Initialize this in your ViewPager's Adapter...
  private FragmentB fragmentB;

  @Override
  void databaseUpdated(boolen updated){
     if(updated && fragmentB != null){
        // call a public method in fragment B to requery the DB
        fragmentB.updateUI();
     }
  }
```

method in `FragmentB`:

```
    public void updateUI(){
       // ... Perform the work to requery DB and display its results 
       // in the UI

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your `Callback` tutorial ;-) I've done something very similar and I see that my refresh function is called. But it doesn't work: SecondFragment frag = (SecondFragment ) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.activity_main_viewPager + ":1");
        if (frag!= null) {
            frag.refreshView();
        }

Comment: @Kody no problem, this should work for your situation. Just make sure to use the callback when items are added which will call to refresh the UI with new items.